# Journal recommendations

Tags: books

I am an 2nd year undergraduate student, majoring in Mathematics. I am interested in computer science as a whole. Are there any journals/magazines which might be accessible to read, so as to get a better flavour of the field ? (besides the assignments and tests that already are part of general coursework).

Comment: What do you mean "accessible to read"? You can search for top conferences in computer science, perhaps of a subarea you find interesting, and check out some interesting papers. Typically, the papers while defining concepts central to them are intended for a professional audience and will not be accessible in a sense of a textbook aimed at undergrads. But do have a look and decide for yourself.

Comment: I doubt the conference proceedings are accessible enough for 2nd year UGs. Maybe check your uni library for [Communications of the ACM](https://cacm.acm.org/). It's usually a broad mix of topics. Should be available in your uni's online library.

Comment: Based on @Kai suggestion: https://dl.acm.org/magazine/xrds "Established in 1994 and published quarterly, XRDS, formerly Crossroads, is the official ACM magazine for student members. Each issue features a theme, such as “Wearable Computing” or “Health Informatics,” and XRDS brings exciting research trends, interviews, columns, and even career advice articles related to that theme and relevant to computer science students. The magazine also lists major conferences, calls for papers, grants and fellowships, and other useful information to help students make the most of their educational careers."

Comment: Ah, I will check them out. Also, any clue how IEEE Xplore magazines/journals are ?